# Manipulate files in Visaul Studio before they are copied to the output folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a knot to some xml resource files before they are build.

The tag I want to add is a unix timestamp, but this doesn't matter.

Comment: perhaps a tt template can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This would be the smartest way. But how to access the timestamp. In my project I wrote a function but it seems I can't access!?

Comment: Got it. I simple implemented the unix timestamp calculation into the template. <#
    DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime sTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    long unixTimeStamp = (long)(datetime - sTime).TotalSeconds;;
#>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post-build event, witch provide to use command-line interface. You can write some util wich will and your tags and run it like this:
[image]

You can find Build events tab in Project Properties page.